# How is the "users" field of `uptime` calculated?

Tags: uptime

For me, `uptime` yields 9 users, but

`ps -Af | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq | wc -l` yields 14.

I'm not exactly sure where the 9 is coming from.

Before I jump to conclusions though, please let me know if you guys do not have such a discrepancy.

Comment: You can use `w` to see more information about those 9 users.  Your `ps -Af` pipeline does not work at all on any of my systems, but have you looked at what it's reporting without using `wc -l`?  It is probably showing some UIDs that don't show up in `uptime`/`w` like `noaccess`, `nobody`, etc

Comment: @Jesse_b I had no idea about `w`. Thank you. Yes, that is indeed what was happening. (On a side note, the -A means 'all', and -f means 'full'. Maybe try -e instead of -A? Idk what version of ps you are using, but mine is procps-ng ps(1)). 

A follow up: what is the difference between users that show up in `w`, and users like `nobody`, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing apples and oranges.

`ps` will list the processes running.  You're then getting the count of unique process-owning user ids.

`uptime` will report the users logged on.  By using utmp.  More details at https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/uptime.c#L177

So, comparison of output, highlighting this, below.

```
# uptime
 16:52:37 up 30 days, 23:32,  1 user,  load average: 0.04, 0.04, 0.05
# w
 16:57:33 up 30 days, 23:37,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
steve    pts/0    cpc79909-stkp12- 16:50    5.00s  0.07s  0.28s sshd: steve [priv]
#


# ps -Af | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq | wc -l
7
# ps -Af | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq
chrony
dbus
polkitd
postfix
root
steve
UID
#
```

Comment: What is the difference between a "user logged on" and a "process-owning user id?" Is there a distinction between a "logged on user" and a special one, like the superuser? I thought that all users essentially were on equal footing.

Comment: So in the example, we've got a process running as username 'postfix'.  That's some process relating to email.  'postfix' is a username.  But it's not a *user*.  Hope this helps.

Comment: it’s not? It is listed in /etc/passwd

Comment: It's a username.  But it's not someone who has logged onto the device.  Folk logging onto the device is what 'uptime' reports.  It doesn't report active processes by username.